# Como se cria um parâmetro opcional em método de uma classe?

Tags: c++, classes, parâmetros

Sei que para criar um parâmetro opcional em uma função você pode fazer isso:

```
void exemplo(int a,int b=0);
```

Mas como faço isso em uma função de uma classe
ex:

```
class Exemplo{
    public:
    void nada(int,int);
};
void Exemplo::nada(int a,int b){}
```

Esse seria um exemplo com parâmetros "normais", para tentar deixar o (b) opcional eu fiz:

```
void Exemplo::nada(int a,int b=0){}
```

porém na hora de chamar a função o compilador diz que eu preciso colocar o (b), provavelmente porque nessa declaração ele não está opcional:

```
void nada(int,int);
```

Como posso resolver esse problema,lembrando que não quero um construtor com parâmetros opcionais e sim uma outra função.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É a mesma coisa:

```
#include <iostream>

class Exemplo {
    public:
    void nada(int a, int b = 0);
};
void Exemplo::nada(int a, int b) { std::cout << b; }

int main() {
    Exemplo x = Exemplo();
    x.nada(1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/G4dCGy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/edhetyph-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/OptionalParamenter.cpp).

Comment: Valeu @Maniero agora ta funcionando eu tinha tentado algo parecido fazendo  void nada(int a, int b = 0); só que depois eu fazia   void Exemplo::nada(int a, int b=0)   por isso tava dando errado.